# Is angular2-highcharts paid ? Can i use it for my Client?

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

This is a general question but i was not able to get the answer for it. Highcharts (https://www.highcharts.com/) is a paid library and it is clearly mentioned in documentation that i need to buy it but what about https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts ? Is this a paid library? I tried to check their licence : It states MIT licence. Does MIT licence means i can use that library for commercial purpose ? I have asked few people and got mixed response.

Comment: https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts#readme (angular2-highcharts) is no longer supported, instead of as a option is to use native javascript highchart from https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts (highchart angular).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this might help. I was going through charts to use in the app I was working on.

Answer is a Yes,
highchart is paid unless you're using it for Non-Commercial use.

Regarding the angular2-highcharts Module, the same thing applies. It's just a wrapper for the angular platform using highchart.js

As a conclusion, if you're using the angular module, you have to go for a  highchart.js paid plan if that's a commercial app. You can use the angular2-highcharts for free

[For more...](https://shop.highsoft.com/highcharts)

Did you try out [ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/)? I am using it and quite enough for the need